# Retrieving the first digit of a number from list of numbers

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

I just started learning Python, and am stuck at this problem:

```
list = [144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025]
```

How do I obtain the first value/element of these numbers? e.g.:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part do you need help with: getting clues from a list, or isolating the first digit of a number?  What have you tried so far, and how does it come up short?

Comment: I am trying to isolate the first digits of these numbers. I tried using index brackets but not sure how to use them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First an aside: Do NOT name your variables `list`. You're obscuring a keyword.

You can convert each number to a string and get the first character:

```
def first_digit(num):
    return int(str(num)[0])
```

Or use recursion:

```
def first_digit(num):
    if num < 10:
        return num
    return first_digit(num // 10)
```

Then just use list comprehension to generate a list:

```
result = [first_digit(n) for n in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with steps which may help you

Traverse through list

For each element find the
Q=10 ^ (number of digits in element - 1)

Divide the number with above value and note down quotient